can we inverse the definition of vector bundles and covector bundles
In differential manifolds, vectors are defined as derivations of functions on manifold $M$, typically $v=\sum_i v_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, and covectors are defined as linear functions of vectors, typically $w = \sum_i w_i dx_i$ or $df = \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} dx_i$. Then we have the action of $df$ to a vector $v$ defined as (by duality):
$$
df(v) = \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} dx_i \sum_j v_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}
=\sum_{ij} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} v_j \delta_{ij} = v(f) .
$$
But it seems to me that we can also define a vector as (intuitively, an infinitesimal change along this direction) the differential
$$
v: = \sum_i v_idx_i ,
$$
and covectors as derivatives
$$
w := \sum_i w_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} .
$$
and then everything else works just as before.
To summarize, I think we can "inverse" the definitions of vector and covector bundles, and interchange their associations to derivatives and differentials. But is this inversion harmless? Or, is the commonly used definition the only option if we do not want logical contradictions?
EDIT: I'm not changing the names here. I am asking why the intuitions about "tangent vectors of curved surfaces" must be related to derivatives but not differentials. I cannot see the fundamental necessity here.

Looks to me like you simply want to switch the names.

You can also call vectors "cows" and covectors "wolves." This will not lead to any logical contradiction, just nobody will understand you.

A vector should be treated as a velocity of a parameterized curve passing through a point. This terminology comes from physics. Given a function and a vector at a point  the directional derivative is the rate of change of the function along the curve. The differential at a point of a function encodes all possible directional directional derivatives. If you feed it a vector, its output is the directional derivative of the function in that direction. It turns out to be a linear function of the vector. Such a thing is called a covector. It’s not a vector. It’s a linear function of vectors.

No, tangent vectors and the covectors (or linear 1-forms) are certainly different. You cannot call covectors vectors, and vice versa. Their difference becomes obvious when you try to change vectors and covectors along smooth maps between spaces.
Suppose $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a smooth map. Then you can define the push forward of the tangent vector on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$,
$$
dF(\partial/\partial x_j) = \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{\partial F_k}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k},
$$
Where $F=(F_1,\cdots,F_m)$ is the $y_k$-components. (This is exactly the chain rule.) Thus, the vector is transformed along the direction same as $F$.
However, the covector is pulled back along $F$. When  you have the differential $dy_k$, you can define the pull back $dF^* dy_k$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
dF^* dy_k = dy_k \circ dF.
$$
All the vectors, vector fields, and tensors have covariant transformation when you change those along the smooth maps, and all the covectors, differential forms, and cotensors have contravariant transformation when you change those along the smooth maps.

Here is a detailed computation for the co/contravariant transformation of vectors and covectors.
Let $F: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth map defined as $F_j(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=y_j$ for each $j=1,\ldots,m$.
Covariant transformation of the tangent vector along $F$:
$$
dF\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{\partial F_k}{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}.
$$
Contravariant transformation of the cotangent vector along $F$:
$$
dy_j = \sum_{k=1}^n dF_j \mapsto \frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_k} dx_k
$$
If we let $DF$ the $k\times j$ matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_1} & \ldots & \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_n} & \ldots & \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_n}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
the above relations can be written as the matrix multiplications,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} 
\\
\vdots 
\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}
\end{bmatrix}=
DF 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y_m}
\end{bmatrix}, \\
\begin{bmatrix}
dy_1
\\
\vdots 
\\
dy_m
\end{bmatrix}=
DF^T 
\begin{bmatrix}
dx_1 \\
\vdots \\
dx_n
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Another example: pull back of the metric along $F$. Suppose we are given a bilinear inner product on the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^m$,
$$
T\mathbb{R}^m \times T\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R},\\
g\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j},\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}\right) =g_{jk}.
$$
Then this can be regared as $(0,2)$-tensor. A $(n,k)$-tensor can be understood as a linear functional that takes $k$ vectors as arguments, and gives a tensor product of $n$ vectors. A tensor product of $0$ vector is defined as a real number.
One of the simpliest choice for the metric is to define $g_{jk}=\delta_{jk}$, which gives $1$ when $j=k$ and $0$ otherwise. This is just the usual Euclidean norm. If we define $G$ as the matrix $(g_{jk})$, then the metric can be defined as
$$
g(V,W) = V^T G W.
$$
Or using the differential notation, we may write
$$
g= \sum_{1\leq j,k\leq m} g_{jk} dy_j \otimes dy_k.
$$
Now $(0,2)$-tensor can be pulled back along $F$, defining a new metric on $\mathbb{R}^m$. The new metric $dF^* g$ is now then defined as
$$
dF^* g = \sum_{1\leq j,k\leq m}\sum_{1\leq p,q \leq n} \frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_p}\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_q} dx_p\otimes dx_q.
$$
Using our matrix notation, the matrix corresponding to $dF^* g$ is
$$
(DF)^T G (DF).
$$
Note that the right multiplication of contravariant element is given by $DF$, not
$(DF)^T$.
Another way of computing those transformation is to use the Einstein notation. In this notation, covariant elements are written with lower indices, and contravariant elements are written with upper indices. That is, we write $dx^j$ and $dy^k$ for the differential forms. $(DF)^k_j$ represents the $(k,j)$-entry of the matrix $DF$. Upper index and the lower index are computed with the contraction, that is, for a covariant element $B$ and contravariant element $A$,
$$
A(B) = \sum_{j} A^j B_j. 
$$
We often omit the summation mark and abusively write $A^j B_j$ for $A(B)$. With this notation, we have
$$
\partial_{x_j} = (DF)^k_j \partial_{y_k}, \\
dy^k = (DF)^k_j dx^j. 
$$
Note here that one subscript and one superscript get disappeared by summation. Using the Einstein notation, the metric is written as
$$
g= g_{jk} dy^j \otimes dy^k,
$$
and the pull back is
$$
dF^* g = (DF)^j_p (DF)^k_q g_{jk} dx^p \otimes dx^q.
$$

Why should vectors be covariant and covectors be contravariant? Why is it natural to use co/contravariant transformations for vectors/covectors?
Note that vectors are defined as the derivation of functions. If $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a smooth map, how should a tangent vector $T_p \mathbb{R}^n\in V$ be transformed? In other words, how could one derivate a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$ using $V$? The only obvious way is to composite,
$$
dF(V)(\phi) = V(\phi\circ F).
$$
Thus, the covariant derivative comes from the chain rule of multivariables,
$$
\frac{\partial (\phi\circ F)}{\partial x_k} = \sum_{j=1}^m \frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_k} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y_j}.
$$
On the other hand, a covector is defined as the linear functional on the tangent space. How could one possibly transform a linear functional $\omega:T_p \mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ along a smooth map $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$? Again, the only obvious transformation is to composite $dF:T_p \mathbb{R}^n\to T_{F(p)}\mathbb{R}^m$,
$$
dF^*(\omega)(V) = \omega(dF(V)).
$$
Composition is a very natural, crucial operation in mathematics, so it is very natural to use composition to transform the vectors and covectors.

Thks a lot! Your answer seems to be what I have been missing all along. But could you please edit this answer and show me briefly how come only the vectors are covariant but not the covectors? I have been long befuddled by this covariant/contravariant calculation.

@Neo Sure. I attached some computations. I also gave another example of how $(0,2)$-tensor (or just a bilinear form) is pulled back along $F$.

@Neo I also added why it is natural to use co(contra)variant transformation for (co)vectors. In short, everything is just composition.
